# Problem deleting files/folders using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, sys

Now I'm sitting and making a Python program to clean up junk on my PC. And everything would be fine, but one problem appeared.
The fact is that I cannot delete files from the “Temp” folder of my profile (the first folder from which files need to be deleted, by the way).

At first I tried to do it like this:

```
os.system(f'cd C:/Users/{current_user}/AppData/Local/Temp')
os.system(f'del /s /q *')
```

However, not only did it not work, **I suddenly almost killed my laptop**, because for some reason the command to delete files extended *not to a specific folder, but to the ENTIRE DISK*.

The second time I did this code:

```
os.system(f'cd C:/Users/{current_user}/AppData/Local/Temp')
os.remove(f'C:/Users/{current_user}/AppData/Local/Temp/')
```

But after running it in the command line (it was enabled in administrator mode at that time), the following error is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\mainProject\GlowClean.py", line 46, in <module>
    easy_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\mainProject\GlowClean.py", line 42, in easy_clean
    os.remove(f'C:/Users/{current_user}/AppData/Local/Temp/')
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:/Users/Home/AppData/Local/Temp/'
```

> Translation: "Отказано в доступе" translated as "Access denied"

**What could be my mistake?**
For a more detailed answer, I’m even ready to insert the full program code into this post.

> **P.S.** Don't judge me harshly because I don't know the obvious, **I'm still new to Python.**

Comment: Each call to `os.system()` invokes a **new** shell.  The second call to `os.system()` did **not** retain the working directory from the first call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **What could be my mistake?**

Your first mistake was trying to use `os.system()` for this purpose.  Python has built-in functions for manipulating files and folders, as well as some good third-party modules.  Use them (more on that later).

When you *do* use `os.system()`, you need to be aware that each call executes the specified command in its own, isolated shell context.  Among the implications is that if you `cd` to a different working directory or modify environment variables then those changes are visible only to the command(s) you are running in that one `os.system()` call.  Thus, your

> ```
> os.system(f'cd C:/Users/{current_user}/AppData/Local/Temp')
> os.system(f'del /s /q *')
> ```

is functionally equivalent to just

```
os.system(f'del /s /q *')
```

alone.  That's unlikely to be what you want.  What it actually tries to delete depends on the working directory for the host `python`.

As far as your second attempt goes, again, using `os.system()` to change the working directory is pointless, but not inherently erroneous.  The issues here are that

1. `os.remove()` applies to regular files only, not directories
2. `os.rmdir()` is the analog for directories, but it applies only to *empty* directories.
3. To remove a whole directory tree, you could use `shutil.rmtree()`, but
4. **You do not want to do this**.  `C:/Users/{current_user}/AppData/Local/Temp/` contains temporary files for *everything* `{current_user}` may be running at the time.  It is not safe to blindly delete its contents, and the folder itself should not be deleted in any case.

Comment: Thank you, everything worked, it cleans where needed.